# Can you make calls with Ubuntu on a Nexus 7?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I'm  considering buying the nexus 7 and installing ubuntu on it, and if it can make calls it will be even better.

Answer (score 4):

This is a known issue / bug:

[LaunchPad > 3G is non-functional on 32GB+3G Nexus 7](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-nexus7/+bug/1091663)

> Repeated attempts to get 3G connectivity on my Nexus 7 fail. The same SIM worked fine under Android.
>
> Very occasionally, a notification pops up saying that I have connected, but I am then immediately disconnected again. Most of the time, though, I get a 'disconnected' notification and nothing else.